# How to detect records that appear on a larger interval than the specified one?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
Col1 Date        Time
A    29/03/2019  00:00
A    29/03/2019  04:00
A    29/03/2019  08:00
A    29/03/2019  12:00
A    29/03/2019  16:00
A    29/03/2019  20:00
A    30/03/2019  00:00
A    30/03/2019  08:00
A    30/03/2019  12:00
A    30/03/2019  16:00
A    30/03/2019  20:00
A    31/03/2019  04:00
```

Basically, the data comes at the interval of `4` hours. I need to return rows that do not fit this criteria.

The expected output:

```
A    30/03/2019  08:00
A    31/03/2019  04:00
```

These are two rows that miss an intermediate record.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a boolean index to identify where the difference between rows is more than 4 hours.

Create a datetime column by adding `Date` and `Time` together, [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas-series-diff) to get the difference between rows, then compare to a TimeDelta.

Modify the TimeDelta (`pd.to_timedelta("4:00:00")`) to change the desired interval.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'A',
                            6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'A', 9: 'A', 10: 'A', 11: 'A'},
                   'Date': {0: '29/03/2019', 1: '29/03/2019', 2: '29/03/2019',
                            3: '29/03/2019', 4: '29/03/2019', 5: '29/03/2019',
                            6: '30/03/2019', 7: '30/03/2019', 8: '30/03/2019',
                            9: '30/03/2019', 10: '30/03/2019',
                            11: '31/03/2019'},
                   'Time': {0: '00:00', 1: '04:00', 2: '08:00', 3: '12:00',
                            4: '16:00', 5: '20:00', 6: '00:00', 7: '08:00',
                            8: '12:00', 9: '16:00', 10: '20:00', 11: '04:00'}})

# Create Index
m = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Date'] + df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y%H:%M'
).diff() > pd.to_timedelta("4:00:00")

# Use Index to Filter DF
out = df[m]

# For Display
print(out)
```

`out`:

```
   Col1        Date   Time
7     A  30/03/2019  08:00
11    A  31/03/2019  04:00
```